# Positioning triple slot graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express, headers

If there are two gtx 570 dc ii's:

[image: gtx 570 dc ii]

On a Gigabyte z68x-ud7-b3 motherboard, in slots PCIe16_1 and PCIe8_2:

[image: Gigabyte z68x-ud7-b3 motherboard]

Will the headers for front panel connections be blocked, or will there be enough flex in the cables to wrap underneath?

**EDIT:** If anyone else comes to this question trying to SLI triple slot cards, the only mobo I have come across with full clearance for two triple width cards and a slot between them for airflow is the [ASUS P8P67 WS Revolution](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8P67_WS_Revolution/)

**EDIT 2:** System arrived, and guess what? They clear the headers, just, although I doubt they would clear the usb3 headers as the cable is sturdier.

Comment: The second card would be going in an 8x PCI-e slot. Shame there isn’t more coordination between vendors.

Comment: that thing is huge.

Comment: 2 of those plus a nh-d14 hanging off the side of my mobo, enclosed in a HAF X case. Almost needed help getting it up the stairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of my motherboard (MSI 890FXA-GD65 AMD Socket AM3) is very similar in that area.

[image]

I have a dual-slot graphics card in that particular slot. Since yours is a triple slot, then yes, it will cover the USB.

As far as overhead, it looks like your heatguard on that graphics card is of similar height to mine as well (MSI Radeon HD 6970 Lightning, for reference).

[image]

I can say that the cables probably would be able to flex and fit under it, though it would be tight. At first, before I rewired it (first cabling was hasty and kinda crappy), I ended up having to wedge the cables under the graphics card because they were hitting against the card's fans. It's better cabled now, but they were flexible enough that there was little to no overhead from them sticking up from the board. The only thing I'd really worry about is how high the connection sticks up. The wire, so long as you don't force it to bend so that it breaks, probably would be fine.

Comment: Cheers for that. I have been told by the mob who are building it that there should be no problems but I wanted a second opinion because it looked like it would be blocked/tight.

Comment: @theraven Feel free to mark it as an answer, then. :)